# Why does this integral of a real, analytic, absolutely integrable function give a complex result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am using Mathematica to develop some ``interesting" problems for students to solve using Fourier series.

The following computation seems as though it should yield a real result:

$B_n = \int_0^1 \exp(-9 x^2) \cos(n \pi x)\, dx~~ n\in Integers,~n\ge 0$

When I code this in Mathematica, I find it returns a complex result, which does not seem plausible.  Here is the code for the first term $(n=0)$ (which is simpler than the general case):

```
B[0] = Integrate[Exp[-9x^2], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}]
```

This returns $\tfrac{1}{6}\sqrt{\pi} \,\textrm{erf}{(3)}$, which is the correct answer.

However, when I compute the integral for the values of $n>0$, I find the following:

```
B[n_] = 2 Integrate[Exp[-9x^2] Cos[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers && n > 0 &&  x ∈ Reals}]
```

Returns:
$\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{1}{36} \pi ^2 n^2} \left[\text{erf}\left(3-\frac{i \pi  n}{6}\right)+\text{erf}\left(3+\frac{i \pi 
   n}{6}\right)\right]$

This is a bit baffling.  I see no reason that we should have wandered into the complex plane to compute this integral.  Anyone have some perspective here?

Thanks.

Comment: All the imaginary parts are zero, so in fact it's a real result expressed in terms of complex numbers.

Comment: I noticed that, but I am unable to prove it.  In other words, there should be a simple way to explicitly show that the complex terms cancel.  So far, I am not able to do so.  Any ideas would help!

Comment: I think it follows from `Conjugate[Erf[Conjugate[z]]] // FullSimplify`. (See for example, the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) and the ["identity theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).)

Comment: Another "proof": `1/6 E^(-(1/36) n^2 \[Pi]^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Erf[Conjugate[z]] + Erf[z]) // Im // FullSimplify[#, n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers] &`

Comment: As for how the complex components arose, I think `TrigToExp[Exp[-9x^2] Cos[n Pi x]]` puts the integrand in a form that reveals where `Erf[]` with a complex argument comes from.

Answer (score 3):

First, `Erf[z] + Erf[Conjugate[z]]` is real since `Conjugate[Erf[Conjugate[z]]] == Erf[z]`:

```
Conjugate[Erf[Conjugate[z]]] // FullSimplify

(*  Erf[z]  *)
```

The following shows how one might come up with the *Mathematica* solution by hand.

First expand the integrand in terms of the exponential function:

```
Exp[-9 x^2] Cos[n Pi x] // TrigToExp

(*  1/2 E^(-I n π x - 9 x^2) + 1/2 E^(I n π x - 9 x^2)  *)
```

Each term is of the form `E^(I 2 B x - A^2 x^2)`, with `A` and `B` real.  The two terms differ in the sign of `B`.  Each term has an integral in terms of `Erf` and `Erfi`, and the `Erfi` from each term cancel out.

```
Integrate[ E^(I 2 B x - A^2 x^2), {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> A > 0 && B ∈ Reals]
% /. B -> -B
% + %% // Simplify
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{B^2}{A^2}}
>    \left(\text{erf}\left(A-\frac{i
>    B}{A}\right)+i\,
>    \text{erfi}\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)\right)}{2 A}$$
>
> $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{B^2}{A^2}}
>    \left(\text{erf}\left(A+\frac{i
>    B}{A}\right)-i\,
>    \text{erfi}\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)\right)}{2 A}$$
>
> $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{B^2}{A^2}}
>    \left(\text{erf}\left(A-\frac{i
>    B}{A}\right)+\text{erf}\left(A+\frac{i
>    B}{A}\right)\right)}{2 A}$$